# css - background at top right is jagged

Tags: css

as you can see here:
[alt text http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/516/newp.png](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/516/newp.png)

the background is not even

the site can be found here:

http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=37

how can i even it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities:

- Your `<div id="wrapper">` has a padding of 10px to the top. Set it to `0` instead.
- Decrease the width of `<div id="wrapper">` to fit the background image's width.
- Make the background image wider. The width of `<div id="wrapper">` is `1050px` so your background image should be at least that wide.

Btw with tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox you can easily debug such things.

Comment: the problem is i dont think i can edit the html of a joomla document. or can i?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the background, ../images/bgr.png, is not wide enough for the design, add a few more pixels to the inside white part to get it out to where it needs to be.